# Como dividir un programa relativamente grande sin que se apilen llamadas a funciones?

Tags: python, algoritmos

-Aunque la pregunta puede aplicar para cualquier lenguaje, establecere mis ejemplos en Python. Pues bien, la pregunta seria: como evitar que las llamadas a las funciones se apilen y a la vez dividir el programa en partes, es decir ...

```
def hacer_algo():
    print('Acabas de hacer algo')
def hacer_otra_cosa():
    print('Acabas de hacer otra cosa')
def menu_inicial():
    print("""
    1) Hacer algo
    2) Hacer otra cosa
    3) Salir
    """) 
    eleccion = int(input('-> '))
    if eleccion == 1:
        hacer_algo()
        menu_inicial()
    elif eleccion == 2:
        hacer_otra_cosa()
        menu_inicial()
    elif eleccion == 3:
        quit()

menu_inicial()
```

-Pues bien, rapidamente nos podemos dar cuenta de que si usamos este script un rato, las llamadas a la funcion se apilarian masivamente, de hecho, esto se puede ver si, despues de un rato, forzamos la salida del programa (cntrl + c)  ...

```
File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 21, in <module>
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 14, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 17, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 14, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 17, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 14, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 17, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 14, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 17, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 14, in menu_inicial
    menu_inicial()
  File "/home/santiago/Escritorio/Programacion/Bloque de estudio de Python/Sintaxis Basica/Practicas/Base de datos Buena/pruebas2.py", line 11, in menu_inicial
    eleccion = int(input('-> '))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

-Lo que esta pasando aqui es que, al llamar a una funcion dentro de otra, la primera nunca termina, haciendo que las llamadas a la funcion se 'apilen', pues bien, esto es obviamente un problema de optimizacion que no se como arreglar, por ejemplo, suele ser de mi interes que, una vez seleccionada una opcion el programa vuelva al `menu_inicial()`, sin embargo, aplicando esta metodologia se apilarian las llamadas a la funcion, generando un problema de optimizacion, pero a la vez el uso de `goto` obviamente no es una opcion ... Alguna sugerencia ?

Comment: Y no sería más fácil usar un loop para imprimir el menú principal, y en ese mismo loop recoger la opción seleccionada, llamar a la función y dejar que vuelva al inicio del bucle donde pintará otra vez el menú, así una y otra vez hasta que decidas salir del mismo? Y evitas el stacking completamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas empleando recursión cuando basta con iterar. He aquí el código reconvertido:

```
def hacer_algo():
    print('Acabas de hacer algo')
def hacer_otra_cosa():
    print('Acabas de hacer otra cosa')
def menu_inicial():
    while True:
        print("""
        1) Hacer algo
        2) Hacer otra cosa
        3) Salir
        """) 
        eleccion = int(input('-> '))
        if eleccion == 1:
            hacer_algo()
        elif eleccion == 2:
            hacer_otra_cosa()
        elif eleccion == 3:
            break

menu_inicial()
```

Como ves, la estrategia es entrar en un ciclo infinito. En cada iteración pides una opción, la ejecutas y repites todo de nuevo. Cuando la opción elegida es "salir", haces un `break` para escapar del ciclo infinito y terminar la ejecución.